# upsert query is not working in room database for returned data from api

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@ExperimentalPagingApi
class AnimeRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
    val AnimeDb: AnimeDatabase,
    val jikanApi: jikanApi
):RemoteMediator<Int,AnimeEntity>() {
    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, AnimeEntity>,
    ): MediatorResult {
       return try {

           val loadkey = when(loadType){
               LoadType.REFRESH ->1
               LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = false)
               LoadType.APPEND -> {


          val pageNo = Constants.name.toInt()
                   Log.d("check","append is working ${pageNo +1}")
                   pageNo+1

               }
           }

           delay(2000L)
           val anime = jikanApi.getAnimeList(
               currentPage = loadkey,
               pageSize = state.config.pageSize
           )
           Log.d("check","anime is working ${anime.pagination.currentPage}")

Constants.name = anime.pagination.currentPage.toString()
           AnimeDb.withTransaction {
if (anime.pagination.currentPage == 24){
    Log.d("check", "animeEntity size for page 24: ${anime.data.size}")
}
                  val animeEntity = anime.data.map {it.toAnimeEntity()}
                  Log.d("check","update is working ${anime.pagination.currentPage}")

                  AnimeDb.dao.upsertAll(animeEntity)
             // }

           }
            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = !anime.pagination.hasNextPage)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

```
my logcat:
  anime is working 2
  update is working 2
 append is working 3
 anime is working 3
 update is working 3
  append is working 4
  anime is working 4
 update is working 4
 append is working 5
 anime is working 5
  update is working 5
 append is working 6
 anime is working 6
  update is working 6
append is working 7
 anime is working 7
  update is working 7
 append is working 8
 anime is working 8
  update is working 8
  append is working 9
anime is working 9
 update is working 9
  append is working 10
 anime is working 10
  update is working 10
  append is working 11
 anime is working 11
  update is working 11
 append is working 12
 anime is working 12
  update is working 12
  append is working 13
anime is working 13
  update is working 13
 append is working 14
 anime is working 14
 update is working 14
  append is working 15
  anime is working 15
  update is working 15
 append is working 16
 anime is working 16
  update is working 16
 append is working 17
  anime is working 17
  update is working 17
  append is working 18
  anime is working 18
  update is working 18
 append is working 19
  anime is working 19
 update is working 19
  append is working 20
 anime is working 20
  update is working 20
  append is working 21
  anime is working 21
  update is working 21
  append is working 22
 anime is working 22
 update is working 22
  append is working 23
  anime is working 23
  update is working 23
  append is working 24
  anime is working 24
  animeEntity size for page 24: 20
```

I am fetching data from an Api and till page 23 it is working fine but at page 24 as you can see in the logcat that api is returning data but 'AnimeDb.dao.upsertAll(animeEntity)' is not doing anything and in result loading  of list is stoping but here i didn't mention in code but i skipped 24 page number to check if list is getting loaded and yes it was getting loaded till 30 page number and then it stopped again  , can anyone tell me what is the issue and how to fix it